# How does Facebook identify users across different app store vendors without requiring login?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Here's an example of what I mean:

-- brand new ios install --

1. User downloads facebook
2. User signs into facebook
3. User downloads instagram
4. Instagram allows user to sign in with the facebook account they just signed in with

Normally this could be accomplished using vendor id/app groups, however Instagram and the Facebook app are released on the app store under different vendors (Instagram, Inc. and Facebook Inc., respectively).

Is there a way to identify a user with a high degree of confidence across two apps (that you control) under different app store developer accounts?